# How to check something at regular intervals?

Tags: android

Beginner here, I have a simple question.

In Android what would be the best what to check for something at regular intervals?

Please bear with me, I'll try to explain the best I can --

For example my audio app is very simple, a main activity and a service. The main activity has a UI with two buttons, start and stop audio. I press start and the audio service starts. Likewise when I click Stop the service stops and the audio ends. If `isLooping()` is hard-coded to true there is no issue because the audio never ends unless I hit stop button, which stops the audio service and also resets the button states.

This is an issue now because I set `isLooping()` to false so the audio doesn't loop. So the audio will stop playing but the service is still running.

I want to be able to detect when the audio stops so I can set the states of the UI buttons. So I need something that is always checking whether audio is playing (i.e. check `player.isPlaying()` so I can end the service and set the enable/disable state of the buttons.

I figured out binding to the service so I can access the `MediaPlayer` controls via my main activity so I know the code to check if it's playing, but WHERE do I put this code so it's checked all the time?

Am I making sense? I know this is probably very simple. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can repeat it with the TimerTask and Timer. Code below:

```
public final void RepeatSoundFunction(){ 

      t = new Timer();
      tt = new TimerTask() {

          @Override
          public void run() {
              mp.seekTo(0); //Reset sound to beginning position
              mp.start();  //Start the sound
              t.purge();  //Purge the sound
          }

      };
      t.schedule(tt, 10*1000); //Schedule to run tt (TimerTask) again after 10 seconds         
}
```

then you set a MediaPlayer onCompletionListener and in there you put this.

Inside the run-code you can check for other things than
music, I just show an example with the audio.

Comment: First of all, thanks your code worked for me. But as the question suggests, @ShadowGod is a beginner. You should explain your answers and FOLLOW GOOD NAMING CONVENTIONS (t, tt should be timer or timerTask or mediaTimer..). This will help the beginners to follow good coding practice. Again, no offense. We all are on the same page. :)